# In SQL Server 2005, when does a Select query block Inserts or Updates to the same or other table(s)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In the past I always thought that select query would not blocks other insert sql. However, recently I wrote a query that takes a long time (more than 2 min) to select data from a table. During the select, a number of insert sql statements were timing out.

If select blocks insert, what would be the solution way to prevent the timeout without causing dirty read?

I have investigate option of using isolation snapshot, but currently I have no access to change the client's database to enable the “ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION”.

Thanks

Comment: What isolation level does your select run under? Seems it must be higher than `readcommitted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When does a `Select` query block Inserts or Updates to the same or
>   other table(s)?

When it holds a lock on a resource that is mutually exclusive with one that the insert or update statement needs.

Under `readcommitted` isolation level with no additional locking hints then the `S` locks taken out are typically released as soon as the data is read. For `repeatable read` or `serializable` however they will be held until the end of the transaction (statement for a single select not running in an explicit transaction).

`serializable` will often take out range locks which will cause additional blocking over and above that caused by the holding of locks on the rows and pages actually read.

Comment: So, in a typical situation, after the read is completed, it will release the lock and allows insert again, please correct me if I am wrong? What if there are multiple select to different tables in the same connection? Does it release the lock only if the connection is closed, or right after the select query is completed?

Comment: @dsum - Yes. Unless your insert is requesting a whole table lock or something.

Answer (score 0):

`READPAST` might be what you're looking for - check out [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-nolock-and-readpast-table-hints-in-sql-server/6185492).

Comment: This won't help blocked insert statements.